# Recordset.Update Database or Object is read-only

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, recordset

Not sure this is going to work in the specifics I intend. The scenario is the text boxes are populated with data from a table, and the user edits the records and clicks a button to save.

```
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rstEdit As DAO.Recordset
Set cdb = CurrentDb
DataValues = "SELECT * FROM Companies, Link_Table WHERE Companies.CompanyID =  " & SelectedValue & ";"
Set rstEdit = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(DataValues, dbOpenSnapshot)

With rstEdit
 OldCompanyName = !CompanyName
 OldCompanyDescription = !Description
 OldFriendlyName = !FriendlyName
 OldAddressLine1 = !AddressLine1
 OldAddressLine2 = !AddressLine2
 OldAddressLine3 = !AddressLine3
 OldTown = !Town
 OldPostcode = !AddressPostcode
 OldCounty = !AddressCounty
 OldMainTelephone = !MainTelephone
 OldMainEmail = !MainEmail
 OldWeb = !WebAddress
```

'Not sure this is necessary. It was quoted in the example, but unsure why? ^'

```
 !CompanyName = NewCompanyName
 !Description = NewCompanyDescription
 !FriendlyName = NewFriendlyName
 !AddressLine1 = NewAddressLine1
 !AddressLine2 = NewAddressLine2
 !AddressLine3 = NewAddressLine3
 !Town = NewTown
 !AddressPostcode = NewPostcode
 !AddressCounty = NewCounty
 !MainTelephone = NewMainTelephone
 !MainEmail = NewMainEmail
 !WebAddress = NewWeb
 .Update
End With
```

However, on clicking the save button, it errors stating that the Database or object is read only, and I'm unsure why. As far as I know it isn't open anywhere, nor should it get opened for any reason! Was hoping someone would be able to shed some light on the issue. The table has a primary key set, which is CompanyID however this isn't used in the routine.

Answer (score 3):

The Type parameter `dbOpenSnapShot` in:

```
Set rstEdit = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(DataValues, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

makes rstEdit open as a read-only recordset(or snapshot). Consider using `dbOpenDynaset` instead.

Comment: Great answer! Also, make sure you have a primary key for the table you are wanting to update. That was my other problem

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, the `dbOpenSnapshot` option results in a read-only recordset.  However once you change the `OpenRecordset` option, you will still be left with a read-only recordset.

The query used as the recordset source includes an [implicit cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_join#Cross_join) between `Companies` and `Link_Table`. The means every row from `Companies` is matched with every row from `Link_Table`.  And that means Access will consider the query read-only which in turn means the recordset will also be read-only.

Build and test a new query in the query designer where you explicitly define a `JOIN` condition.  Start with something simple; leave out the `WHERE` clause until after you have a working `JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    Companies
    INNER JOIN Link_Table
    ON Companies.link_field = Link_Table.link_field;
```

Notes:

1. If the two tables don't include a common field (or set of fields) which you can use as *link_field*, the task will be much more challenging ... and you may not even be able to open an editable recordset.
2. If the `JOIN` is one-to-many, you should be able to edit fields from the table on the "many" side, but may not be able to edit fields from the table on the "one" side of the `JOIN`.

Comment: Still the same problem with `dbOpenDynaset` Going to research this one a bit and see if i can come up with anything still not tried the  new query… yet

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying editable `LockEdits` argument in your OpenRecordset method.

```
 Set recordset=object.OpenRecordset(source, type, options, lockedits)
```

You create an editable recordset when you use one of the following constants in the `LockEdits` argument of the `OpenRecordset` method:

```
dbOptimistic, dbPessimistic, dbOptimisticValue, or dbOptimisticBatch
```

**Source** VBA: Run-Time Error '3027' Using ODBCDirect to Open RecordSet: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161252