# Runtime Error: 3027 Database or Object is read-only

Tags: ms-access

I am doing a simple status update to a table and an appending of a string to an existing field. After a specific record is found from a SQL statement, coding is to execute an update of the 'StatusNumber' field in one table and the 'StatusComments' field in another table is to insert new comments with a date appending to already existing comments.

```
Sub VATApprovalAttempt()
    
    Dim db As dao.Database
    Dim rs As dao.Recordset
    
    Dim emailTo As String
    Dim emailSubject As String
    Dim emailText As String
    Dim UPDATE As String
            
            If rs.Fields("StatusNumber").Value = 12 Then
                     rs.Edit
                     rs.Fields("StatusNumber").Value = 4
                     rs.UPDATE
                     
                End If

                If Not IsNull(rs.Fields("StatusComments").Value) Then
                    rs.Edit
                    rs.Fields("StatusComments").Value = rs.Fields("StatusComments").Value & Date & " - VAT Rep’s endorsed & Product request box received"
                    rs.UPDATE

                End If
```

The 3027 error occurs in line with: rs.Edit for both IF statements. Any ideas why it thinks this is a read-only object? I have done similar programs in other databases, but this one seems to be causing trouble.

Comment: Would probably be better to have each comment as its own record in a related dependent table. Not showing code to set and open recordset object. Why is UPDATE declared as a string variable? UPDATE is an intrinsic method of recordset object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recordset.Edit or Update sql vba statement fastest way to update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894045/recordset-edit-or-update-sql-vba-statement-fastest-way-to-update). Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431018/recordset-update-database-or-object-is-read-only

Answer (score 0):

Are we missing the bit of your code that sets the value of rs?
You need something like:

`Set rs = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("TableName", dbOpenDynaset)`

before you can edit rst. I assume that you must be doing this somewhere or you'd get an "Object variable not set" type error. Notice I refer to "Currentdb" rather than your db variable above as this would need to be set too otherwise.

I'm having a similar problem though with something that updated just fine a couple of days ago so if I discover something useful I'll come back.